# The constructor of type is not applicable as the formal varargs element type is not accessible here

Tags: java

I don't understand why this code doesn't compile

It seems that it doesn't recognize "Nombre" as an "Expression". The problem is that "Nombre" implements "Expression" (which is an interface).
Do you have any idea where the problem might come from ?

This is where it causes compilation error:

```
private static void testMoyenneToString(){        

        Moyenne s = new Moyenne(new Nombre(10), new Nombre(10)); 
        assert(s.toString().equals("(10*10)")); 

        s = new Moyenne(new Nombre(10), new Nombre(-10)); 
        assert(s.toString().equals("(10*(-10))")); 
    }
```

This is Moyenne.java :

```
package calc;

public class Moyenne extends Naire {
    public Moyenne(Expression... operandes) {
        super(operandes);
    }

    public int valeur() {
        int somme = 0; 
        for (Expression e : super.operandes) {
            somme += e.valeur(); 
        }
        return somme/super.operandes.length; 
    }

    public String getOperateur() {
        return "Moyenne" ;
    }
}
```

this is Nombre.java :

```
package calc;

public class Nombre implements Expression {
    protected int val; 

    public Nombre(int val) {
        this.val = val; 
    }

    public int valeur(){
        return this.val; 
    }

    public String toString(){
        return Integer.toString(this.val);  
    }
}
```

This is Expression.java (interface) :

```
package calc;

interface Expression {
    int valeur(); 
    String toString(); 
}
```

This is the error I get from the compilation :

```
javac -encoding "iso-8859-1" calc/tests/TestExpression.java
calc/tests/TestExpression.java:164: error: constructor Moyenne in class Moyenne cannot be applied to given types;
        Moyenne s = new Moyenne(new Nombre(10), new Nombre(10)); 
                    ^
  required: Expression[]
  found: Nombre,Nombre
  reason: formal varargs element type Expression is not accessible from class TestExpression
calc/tests/TestExpression.java:167: error: constructor Moyenne in class Moyenne cannot be applied to given types;
        s = new Moyenne(new Nombre(10), new Nombre(-10)); 
            ^
  required: Expression[]
  found: Nombre,Nombre
  reason: formal varargs element type Expression is not accessible from class TestExpression
2 errors
```

This is my UML diagram to help you understand the overall organization here : [image]

Comment: The interface `Expression` is not `public`?

Comment: it is public yes

Comment: Not according to the source code you have added to your question.

Comment: Ok it was private my bad. I didn't know that it sets interface as private when you don't mention public before it.

Comment: Thank you guys !